# Save data after closing the website?

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net and I want to save data of shopping cart after I close the website of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
Then when I go and re-run [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) the data of shopping cart is still there.

Is that possible?

---

**Edit**

Thanks AVD. Edited the answer in here. This is for anyone who have queries on where to place the  code

Place this code in web.config

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="PostalCode" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

View [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) for more info. As stated by AVD.

Comment: Vote AVD up then if he answered your qustion

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) state. The `Profile` state uses database so you may preserve user-session data even after user is leaving.